# Geometric progression question. Year less?

Tags: sequences-and-series, geometric-progressions

Here is the math question.

> A 100m cliff erodes by 2/7 of its height each year.
>
> (a) What will the height of the cliff be after 10 years?

This is how I worked out the question.

```
100*(5/7)^10
```

Which is `3.46m` to 2d.p.

However my teacher said that it is wrong (to the whole class and also insulted me a bit >_>) and that I didn't follow this formula.

```
Tn = ar^(n-1)
```

And that I should have done

```
100(5/7)^9
```

Which is instead `4.84m` to 2d.p.

---

This doesn't make sense because if you used the formula and the question was

> What will the height of the cliff be after 1 year?

```
 100(5/7)^(1-1)
=100(5/7)^0
=100
```

That doesn't make sense at all!

**Am I right or is the teacher right?**

**ADDITIONALLY** my teacher said his answer is an interpretation of the question. *Is his answer a valid interpretation of this question? Or is it just incorrect mathematics?*

---

**BTW** Also my teacher said my answer has no common sense and that I won't be able to do the HSC well if I keep reading questions wrong.

Comment: Your argument looks OK. $\frac{5}{7}$ th is left after each year, so after $10$ years it should be $(\frac{5}{7})^{10}$ th left of the original. So you are $\color{blue}{right}$. And you have checked it out for the base case. +1 for laying it out so neatly and checking it.

Comment: With the way you have phrased the question, I agree with your answer.  It is always good to take formulae and check them against extreme cases (such as after no years elapse or after "*infinitely many*" years pass) to make sure they make sense.  It is possible that the exact phrasing as it was originally given was slightly different (*or intended to be different*), which just highlights the importance of precise wording in mathematics.  (*for example, it could have been worded as "in 2001 the height was... what is the height in 2010?"*)

Comment: Also I believe the textbook answer follows the teacher's way. Bad question? Bad answer?

Comment: Also the question I put up there is the exact same to the one in the textbook word by word.

Comment: @Bradman175 the teacher is not always right. You will do fine as a student. Your teacher is using a formula that will find the 10th term of a sequence, not the same as what was asked in the question as you posed it here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, we agree that $T_{n+1} = (5/7) T_n,$ so $T_n = T_0 (5/7)^n$. Clearly, after $0$ years, the height of the tree is $100$, so you have $T_n = 100 (5/7)^n$.

Hence, after one year, we have
$$
T_1 = 100 (5/7)
$$
and after 10 years, we have
$$
T_1 = 100 (5/7)^{10}
$$
as you have claimed.

Comment: I showed my teacher this and he told me to go away. He also said you're an idiot. Help.

Comment: I made an addition to my question.

Comment: @Bradman175 does not really influence the answer -- yours is the correct one

Answer (score -2):

$T_n = ar^n-1$

$T_1 = 100\left(\frac57\right)^1-1= 100m $

So $T_{10}=100\left(\frac57\right)^{10}-1= 4.84m $

So your teacher is correct